# iOS: SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored originalTransaction == nil

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an app which has auto renewable subscriptions, the purchasing of these are fine, however if a user deletes the app and attempts to restore the subscriptions at a later date I'm not getting back the data that'd expect.

According to [apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransaction_Class/Reference/Reference.html), I should recieve an originalTranscation with the details of the initial transaction, in most cases and on the sandbox this is exactly what is happening however on some of our customers live apps we are receiving a nil value for the originalTransaction.

Can anyone think why I would not receive the originalTransaction back? The date sent back in [transaction transactionDate] is the same as I'd expect from [[transaction originalTransaction] transactionDate] however I don't know whether it's safe to assume that if the originalTransaction is nil that the [transaction transactionDate] will always be the date of the originalTransaction.

Comment: just go through this ..
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537663/ios-how-to-get-a-list-of-already-purchased-products

Answer (score 1):

I was having exact same issue. I resolved it by checking if original transaction is nil return the current transaction.

here is the code i replaced in `- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction`

```
if (transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier) {
    [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
} else {
    [self provideContentForProductIdentifier:transaction.payment.productIdentifier];
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain this in details?

Comment: @Gauravakasparsh while testing I found that the server was returning nill for some of the original transactions, for that I placed an if condition and replaced it with the current transaction if its nill.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, same was happening with me and i fixed it too by handling nil.

Comment: @Sam Actually, I found that transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier is always returned correctly, but transaction.originalTransaction.transactionReceipt is 
always 'null'.

So, my test is:

if(transaction.originalTransaction.transactionReceipt == nil){
   // pass transaction
}
else{
   // transaction.originalTransaction
}