# Ios how to get a list of already purchased products?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, product, verify

I'm building an app that uses In app purchase. I'm using non-consumable product types.

Everything works ok (setting up products, buying...).

What I would like to do is to verify which products a user had already purchased (when reinstalling app or changing device)?

Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See the [Restoring Transactions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/MakingaPurchase/MakingaPurchase.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW1) section of the In-App Purchase guide. Here is what it specifically says:

> Store Kit provides built-in functionality to restore transactions for
>   non-consumable products, auto-renewable subscriptions and free
>   subscriptions. To restore transactions, your application calls the
>   payment queue’s [restoreCompletedTransactions](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentQueue_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKPaymentQueue/restoreCompletedTransactions) method. The payment queue
>   sends a request to the App Store to restore the transctions. In
>   return, the App Store generates a new restore transaction for each
>   transaction that was previously completed.

Answer (score 3):

you can call

```
[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];
```

it will return to you the already completed transactions.

Then you can verify if your product is in the set.

Answer (score 0):

Apple deals with this topic under [Restoring Transactions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/MakingaPurchase/MakingaPurchase.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH3-SW2) in the In-App Purchase Programming Guide.

Basically, what you have to do is send a `restoreCompletedTransactions` message to the payment queue.