# Is there a way to retrieve a list of in-app purchases made with my app?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Suppose there is an app with in-app purchase that uses a web server to verify in-app purchases with Apple and keep records.  Suppose that web server had a bug and wasn't properly processing purchase verification.  Suppose that bug was discovered and fixed.

Does Apple provide any sort of API for retrieving a list of purchases made for an app so that the verification can be re-run and the end users credited with their purchases?  So far googling things like "ios in-app purchase retrieve list of purchases" hasn't turned up very much.

(Yes, said app ought to have been logging that information thus invalidating the need for such an API).

Edit: To be clear, I'm looking to see if there's a way to do this from MY purchase verification server and not involve the client devices.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9537663/ios-how-to-get-a-list-of-already-purchased-products

Comment: Looking for the same end result, but I'm trying to do this from the server side. The product is a consumable, and I don't want to have to push a device update.